# Add string to registry with .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry

I'm just getting started with bat files, but i was wondering if someone could show me how to do the following in a `.bat` file.

I need to add the string value

> "SPaNr"="2"

to

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\AMI\RadWorks\8.0]

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to use reg.exe

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\AMI\RadWorks\8.0 /v SPaNr /d 2
```

Use the /t switch if you need to specify the data type

Comment: @Damian, your data appears to have been provided in `.reg` file string format which means `/T REG_SZ` would be the correct data type. Reg.exe uses the data type REG_SZ as its assumed default so the answer provided by @Richard above needs no alteration or addition.